# Is there any option to remove google map(ver 3.20) infowindow close button. ?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Is there any option to remove google map(ver 3.20) infowindow close button.

Answer (score 1):

According to [google.maps.InfoWindowOptions object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) it's not supported to specify the visibility of `close` button but you could consider the following options:

CSS:

```
.gm-style-iw + div {
    display: none;
}
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/mgurph0d/)

JavaScript:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function(){
    $(".gm-style-iw").next("div").hide();
});
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/nvq5fm7y/)

> Has been tested against `3.21.*`